# Как сравнить две строки, допуская различие в n букв?

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Например есть две строки

"Манчестер Юн.-Барнли" 
и
"Манчестер Юнайтед Бернли"

"Сток Сити-Суонси" и "Сток Суонси"

Как (с помощью Regex) определить, что это одно и то же? Трудность еще в том, что во второй строке нет разделяющего "-".

Comment: Добавьте, пожалуйста, еще несколько примеров.

Comment: если я правильно вас понял, то это одно и тоже сточки зрения смысла текста. К сожалению ловить смысловую идентичность с помощью регулярок не получится, тут нужно что-то сложнее, если делать полную автоматику, или можно обойтись словарем синонимов. Причина проста, слова имеют смысл для нас, для машины это набор символов, не более, особенно касательно естественных языков. Поиск опечаток можно автоматизировать в некоторой степени, но не полностью, и не регулярками.

Comment: С помощью только одних регулярок Вы это не реализуете, проблема куда глубже.

Comment: Ну а если взять два слова, в которых одна произвольная буква отличается? Например Барнли и Бернли.

Comment: Это вам про расстояние Левенштейна почитать надо, начать можно отсюда https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%9B%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0

Comment: Брать из каждого слова по символу, если идентичны, то `true`. По итогу сравнения выводить процент совпадений. На основе результата делать выводы.

Comment: @Pollux, если вторая строка целиком сдвинута относительно первой - будет 0% совпадений.  Нужно не изобретать велосипеды, а брать известные алгоритмы нечеткого сравнения. Биоинформатики каждый день сравнивают "похожие" строки.

Comment: @Nofate, согласен насчет строки, но вопрос в комментарии был по поводу слова.

Comment: Отсутствие одной буквы в слове тоже очень вероятный случай.

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии. Пока буду разбивать строки на слова и сравнивать по-простому. Потом засяду за нечеткие сравнения.

Answer (score 1):

Для примеров в вопросе достаточно проверить, что для каждого слова в одной строке есть слово из другой строки, которое с него начинается. Если все ситуации именно такие, то можно собрать решение "на коленке" без сторонних библиотек.

Чтобы разбить строки на массивы из слов, можно:

1. заменить всё, что не буквы, на пробелы
2. сократить повторяющиеся пробелы
3. проверить, что получившиеся строки не пустые (иначе задача снимается)
4. перевести строки в нижний регистр
5. разбить по пробелам на массивы из слов

Затем сравнить слова попарно, и если все слова одной строки поглотились словами из другой, то всё ок. В PHP можно найти [позицию первого вхождения подстроки](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strpos.php) и сравнить её с нулём. Про джаву не знаю, но, думаю, тоже можно подобрать удобную штатную функцию.

Answer (score 0):

Регексом вряд ли можно добится нужного тебе эфекта. Как и другими встроенными методами.

Тебе нужна либа для Text comparation. Попробуй погуглить по "Sequence Comparison Algorithm" или "Text comparison algorithm".

Вот здесь должен лежать нужный тебе алгоритм, в том числе и на джава-реализации:
https://github.com/cubicdaiya/onp

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Не могли бы вы добавить поясняющий пример?

Answer (score -1):

Точно есть готовые либы для javaдля нечеткого поиска. https://github.com/iamsimakov/Kursovoi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/simakov_alexey/kursovoi/TaskSortingExpressions.java

Там используется библиотека от апач.

Comment: Это тема про расстояние Левенштайна, можно сравнивать и сортировать